# What data in a SAML assertion is digested?

Tags: saml, digest

I'm working with a customer who has built a home-grown engine to generate SAML assertions. We are using ForumSentry to validate the assertion, but the digest is failing to validate. We already have a dozen other customers sending us SAML assertions, for web SSO, perfectly well, and I'm sure ForumSys have many 100's of customers for ForumSentry working perfectly well too.

I've spent many hours trying to understand exactly what the digest is made of and trying to find samples of XML which goes into the digest algorithm. I've failed and I would appreciate some help please.

It seems to me that the only data signed is the reference URI, and not all other the "parameters" of the assertion, such as the subject, issuer, etc. Is this correct / what don't I understand? What is the background to this? If correct, how is the other data protected from tampering?

Is there an assumption that Web SSO must be over HTTPS to protect the integrity of the entire assertion?

What data exactly forms the data that is signed? Could someone post an example please, both pre and post canonicalization of data that is signed.

Any other background info would be great.

Comment: Quoting the SAML Tech overview `SAML defines a number of security mechanisms that prevent or detect such attacks. The primary mechanism is for the relying
party and asserting party to have a pre-existing trust relationship, typically involving a Public Key Infrastructure (PKI). Where message integrity and message confidentiality are required, then HTTP over SSL 3.0 or TLS 1.0 is recommended.
When a relying party requests an assertion from an asserting party then bi-lateral authentication is
required and the use of SSL 3.0 or TLS 1.0 using server and client authentication are recommended.`

Answer (score 4):

SAML uses XML DSig for signing. When a SAML entity (an assertion, an entire Response, metadata etc...) is signed it is done by using specific algorithms in the XML Dsig suite.

- The reference of the signature must point to the ID of the signed entity. For a signed assertion that is the `ID` attribute of the `<assertion>` node.
- The canonicalization algorithm used must be Exclusive Canonicalization. This is nothing that affects the actual XML contents, it is an instruction to the XML parser used by the crypto library that makes sure that whitespace differences etc. won't affect the validity of the signed data.

XML DSig works in two steps:

- First a hash is calculated for each reference in the signature. For SAML signing there should only be one reference to the `ID` attribute of the enclosing entity.
- Then a cryptographic signature is calculated across the XML containing the hashes.

This means that a single signature can be used to verify the integrity of several pieces of XML, but in SAML that functionality is not used.

With each signature containing exactly one reference to the `ID` attribute of the signed entity, the entire entity is protected by the signature.

I'd suggest that you read the [SAML core spec](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/35711/sstc-saml-core-errata-2.0-wd-06-diff.pdf) section 5.4 if you need more details on how the XML signature works with SAML.